# React Typesscript consuming component callback

Tags: reactjs, typescript, callback

How can I use the callback method?

This is the call of the component:

```
//This is the Parent Component
const [selectedDateState, setSelectedDateState] = React.useState();
...
<DateSelection initDate={new Date()} label={"Pick a date"} onValueChange={setSelectedDateState}/>
                                                         {/*^^^^^^^^^^^^ Error */}
```

I get the error message:

```
TS2322: Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<undefined>>' 
is not assignable to type '(newDate: Date) => void'.   
Types of parameters 'value' and 'newDate' are incompatible.     
Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<undefined>'.       
Type 'Date' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: undefined): undefined'.
```

That's the component, a simple date picker.
When I call it, I pass today's date and a label.
If the date is changed, the date should be set in the state in the parent page.

DateSelection.tsx

```
import 'date-fns';
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';
import {
    MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
    KeyboardDatePicker,
} from '@material-ui/pickers';

type ChildProps = {
    initDate: Date, 
    label: string,
    onValueChange: (newDate: Date) => void;
}

export default function DateSelection({initDate, label, onValueChange}: ChildProps) {
    // The first commit of Material-UI
    const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = React.useState<Date>();

    const handleDateChange = (date: Date | null) => {
        if (date) {
            setSelectedDate(date);
            onValueChange(date);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        setSelectedDate(initDate);
    }, [])

    return (
        <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
            <Grid container justify="space-around">
                <KeyboardDatePicker
                    margin="normal"
                    id="date-picker-dialog"
                    label= {label}
                    format="dd.MM.yyyy"
                    value={selectedDate}
                    onChange={handleDateChange}
                    KeyboardButtonProps={{
                        'aria-label': 'change date',
                    }}
                />
            </Grid>
        </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `setSelectedDateState` from `React.useState` has the type signature: `Dispatch<SetStateAction<undefined>>` and you've defined the type for `onValueChange` as `(newDate: Date) => void`.

So you can either change the type for `onValueChange` to be `Dispatch<SetStateAction<Date>>`, where the types `Dispatch` and `SetStateAction` comes from React...

```js
import * as React from "react";

type DateSelectionProps = {
   ...
   onValueChange: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Date>>;
}
```

Or change the component to the following, so you're matching the type signature you've defined for `onValueChange`:

```
const [selectedDateState, setSelectedDateState] = React.useState<Date>();
...
<DateSelection initDate={new Date()} label={"Pick a date"} onValueChange={(date) => setSelectedDateState(date)}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry

I found a solution. I have to use useCallback instead of useState in the parent component!

```
    const handleSelectedDate = useCallback((e)=>{
        console.log(e);
        setSelectedDateState( e );
    },[]);

...

 <DateSelection initDate={new Date()} label={"Pick a date"} onValueChange={ handleSelectedDate }/>
```

Comment: ah, it would work that way too. Thank you for your answer.

Which variant would you recommend
onValueChange = {(date) => setSelectedDateState (date)}
or useCallback?